# in _ViewStart,cshtml, how come the Javascript part does not get executed every time when I goto another page?

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

In the code below which is located in _ViewStart.cshtml, for some reason, 
only what is inside @{ } gets executed everytime when i goto another page, but the javascript part does not, why is this and how do I fix it?

```
<script>

     alert("in side viewstate");
</script>
@{

     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/myLayout.cshtml";
 }
```

Comment: What do you see in the generated source?

Answer (score 4):

This JavaScript code has to be put in the `myLayout.cshtml`, not `_ViewStart`. `_ViewStart.cshtml` is a special view that sets up the Razor variables, not contain the HTML code.

Comment: thanks for your help, after i put the following in side myLayout.cshtml, nothing gets executed @using Cmg.MultiLanguage.Web.MVC

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    
    <script language ="JavaScript" type ="text/javascript">

          alert("in side myLayout");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language ="JavaScript" type ="text/javascript">

        alert("in side myLayout");
    </script>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>